# Django: Set pk of a model as default value in its column

Tags: python, django, database, primary-key

What do I have to do, to assign the pk as a default value? This doesn't work:

```
from django.db import models

class TeamMember(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_listing = models.IntegerField(default=id)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the id is not generated until the object is saved to the database. However using a uuid could solve for this.

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

# unique id to be used as pk for TeamMember table.
unique_id = uuid.uuid4().hex


class TeamMember(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,
        default=unique_id, editable=False
    )
    order_listing = models.IntegerField(default=unique_id)
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this doesn't help, because order_listting has to `auto_increment=True`, which is not provided by `uuid4`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if you want to reset the value of `order_listing` to `id` every time you save the object.

```
from django.db import models

class TeamMember(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_listing = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        self.order_listing = self.id
        return super(TeamMember, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

OR the below code for only setting it for the first time.

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class TeamMember(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_listing = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=TeamMember)
def order_listing_update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.order_listing = instance.id
        instance.save()
```

Comment: Thank you. Isn't there no shorter way like `default=self.id`

Comment: The problem with the second method is, that it doesn't provide the default value in the front end admin dashboard as a preview, when you use the form element.

Comment: In either of the methods, you don't need to add order_listing in the forms for frontend admin. It can be a readonly field.

Comment: default=self.id is exactly what is being implemented in the first method. While saving the object, you set a particular value and then save it. (Save method)